# Bijective map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a specific property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

I am trying to see if there is a bijective map $\Phi$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the property that $\Phi$ maps **every** copy of $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$ to a copy of $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}^2$. By a copy of $\mathbb{N}$ I mean a set that is homeomorphic to the natural numbers (here $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ both have their usual topologies).

Comment: Just one copy of $\Bbb N$, or every copy of $\Bbb N$ in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry, I meant every, I have edited the question.

Comment: One last question: $\Bbb N$ is not only discrete in $\Bbb R$, but also closed. Do you want to consider sets like $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$, which are discrete but not closed in $\Bbb R$, or just sets that are discrete and closed? And if the latter, do you want their images under $\Phi$ to be closed in $\Bbb R^2$ as well as discrete?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, I want the sets to be both discrete and closed. Otherwise, it seems to me that the question would be equivalent to asking whether $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic wrt their cocountable topologies. The answer is obviously yes.

Comment: So he just wants every discrete set mapped to another discrete set?

Comment: @menag I want every discrete closed set to be mapped to another discrete closed set.

Comment: @user319242: Thanks for the clarification. I’m off for some dinner and then bed now, but I’ll give it some thought.

Answer (score 2):

I added a new answer here in the beginning. Maybe i made a mistake! The old answer can still be read in the end of this answer.

Let $I_m := [m, m+1)$ and $I_{(k,l)} := [k, k+1) \times [l, l+1)$. Let $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ be a bijection. Then $I_m \mapsto I_{\varphi(m)}$ defines a bijection between our intervals. Moreover we have the disjoint unions $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} I_m$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 = \bigcup_{(k,l) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} I_{(k,l)}$. Let now $f_m : I_m \to I_{\varphi(m)}$ be bijections and define $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, f(x) = f_m(x)$ if $x \in I_m$. This is obviously a bijection. If now $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a discrete closed set, it has a finite intersection with every $I_m$ (since otherwise, it had a limit point in $\overline{I_m}$ which would not be isolated). Therefore $f(A) \cap I_{\varphi(m)} = f(A \cap I_m)$ is finite too and for every element which is not on the boundary of $I_{\varphi(m)}$ we see that it is isolated. For the boundary points we see by taking $I_{\varphi(m) - (1,0)}, I_{\varphi(m) - (0,1)}, I_{\varphi(m) - (1,1)}$ into account, that these are isolated too. Assume now, that $f(A)$ had a limit point $x$. Then there would be infinitely many points in the ball $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$. This ball intersects at most four $I_{(k,l)}$ which only have finite intersection with $f(A)$ and thus leads to a contradiction. Thus $f(A)$ is closed. In the same way we see that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed an discrete if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed an discrete.

(old answer: Since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable there is a bijection $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{N}$ ("countable sets don't change infinite cardinality"). Extending it yields the desired bijection.)

Comment: Two points. First, you’re assuming that the OP wants just one copy of $\Bbb N$ to be treated properly. This is likely but by no means certain, which is why I asked the question that I did. Secondly, $\Bbb R^2\setminus\Bbb N=\Bbb R^2$, since $\Bbb N$ is disjoint from $\Bbb R^2$; what you mean, I expect, is $\Bbb R^2\setminus(\Bbb N\times\{0\})$ or the like.

Comment: Sorry that I did not write an explicit identification from $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I first wanted to write it down but then thought that it's obvious what I mean. For the first point, I quote:
"a copy of N inside R to a copy of N inside R2. By a copy of N I mean a set that is homeomorphic to the natural numbers"
He's not talking about copies.

Comment: After $40$ years of teaching mathematics I can confidently say that it’s entirely possible that the OP *is* talking about about every copy of $\Bbb N$. It’s less likely than the alternative, but it’s far from being impossible.

Comment: Actually I meant **every** copy of $\mathbb{N}$, I have edited the question.

Comment: Added a (hopefully) correct answer now.